# Reverse geocode leaflet marker - Getting street name and precise address

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, esri

How can I retrieve the complete address of a point on the map? 
I am currently using L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService() which returns the following info - (This is an example)

[image]

Are there reverse geocoders which return the complete address of a place (including Apartment #/ Building #, street and country name (instead of/ in addition to the country code))?

Comment: See the list of [Leaflet plugins for geocoding](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding), and compare the features of the geocoding backends.

Comment: I already read that link before posting this question. What do you mean by  geocoding backends? I am a newbie!

Comment: "Geocoding backends" means "the different services that you can ask and they get you a route back". Each service has different capabilities, formats the results in different ways, and depends on different addresses databases.